# Is it possible to create a YAML file of my current VPC that I built from scratch on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I created a VPC with AWS. Is it possible to use cloudformation to create a yaml file of my vpc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Former2](https://former2.com/):

> Former2 allows you to generate Infrastructure-as-Code outputs from your existing resources within your AWS account. By making the relevant calls using the AWS JavaScript SDK, Former2 will scan across your infrastructure and present you with the list of resources for you to choose which to generate outputs for.

AWS previously provided a similar tool called **CloudFormer**, but it has not been maintained.